# Keeping all the records for specific IDs

Tags: stata

I have the following dataset:

```
clear

input id code cost
1 15342 18
2 15366 12
1 16786 32
2 15342 12
3 12345 45
4 23453 345
1 34234 23
2 22223 12
4 22342 64
3 23452 23
1 23432 22
end
```

I want to get the output below:

```
id    code   cost  
 1   15342     18  
 2   15366     12  
 1   16786     32  
 2   15342     12  
 1   34234     23  
 2   22223     12  
 1   23432     22
```

I tried to use this command but it did not work:

```
keep if id = (1|2)
```

How can I keep all the records for specific IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
keep if id == 1 | id == 2
```

Alternatively, you can use the `inlist()` function:

```
keep if inlist(id, 1, 2)
```

In this particular case (and more generally when the wanted IDs are consecutive), the `inrange()` function will also work:

```
keep if inrange(id, 1, 2)
```

Results in all cases:

```
list, separator(0)

     +-------------------+
     | id    code   cost |
     |-------------------|
  1. |  1   15342     18 |
  2. |  2   15366     12 |
  3. |  1   16786     32 |
  4. |  2   15342     12 |
  5. |  1   34234     23 |
  6. |  2   22223     12 |
  7. |  1   23432     22 |
     +-------------------+
```