# Keep all the records for all IDs with a specific code

Tags: stata

Consider the following data example:

```
clear

input id code cost
1 15342 18
2 15366 12
1 16786 32
2 15342 12
3 12345 45
4 23453 345
1 34234 23
2 22223 12
4 22342 64
3 23452 23
1 23432 22
end
```

How can I keep all the records for the IDs that contain the code `15324` in any row?

This is a follow-up question to a previous one of mine: [Keeping all the records for specific IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860764/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input id code cost
1 15342 18
2 15366 12
1 16786 32
2 15342 12
3 12345 45
4 23453 345
1 34234 23
2 22223 12
4 15342 64
3 23452 23
1 23432 22
end

bysort id (code): egen tag = total(inlist(code, 15342))
keep if tag
```

Results:

```
list, sepby(id)

     +-------------------------+
     | id    code   cost   tag |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |  1   15342     18     1 |
  2. |  1   16786     32     1 |
  3. |  1   23432     22     1 |
  4. |  1   34234     23     1 |
     |-------------------------|
  5. |  2   15342     12     1 |
  6. |  2   15366     12     1 |
  7. |  2   22223     12     1 |
     |-------------------------|
  8. |  4   15342     64     1 |
  9. |  4   23453    345     1 |
     +-------------------------+
```

Note that I changed the data example slightly for better illustration.